# dynamic SQL ERROR: column "age" does not exist

Tags: sql, postgresql, plpgsql

postgres 12

I am trying to loop through a table which has schema , table_names and columns

I want to do various things like finding nulls ,row count etc. I failed at the first hurdle trying to update the col records.

table i am using

```sql
CREATE TABLE test.table_study ( 
    table_schema text,
    table_name text,
    column_name text,
    records int,
    No_Nulls int,
    No_Blanks int,
    per_pop int
);
```

I populate the table with some schema names ,tables and columns from information_schema.columns

```sql
insert into test.table_study select table_schema, table_name,  column_name
from information_schema.columns
where table_schema like '%white' 
order by table_schema, table_name,  ordinal_position;
```

I want to populate the rest with a function

function :-

```sql
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE test.insert_data_population()
as $$
declare s record;
declare t record;
declare c record;

BEGIN

    FOR s IN SELECT distinct table_schema FROM test.table_study
    LOOP
        FOR t IN SELECT distinct table_name FROM test.table_study where table_schema = s.table_schema
        loop
            FOR c IN SELECT column_name FROM test.table_study where table_name = t.table_name
            LOOP        
                                
    execute 'update test.table_study set records = (select count(*) from ' || s.table_schema || '.' || t.table_name || ') where table_study.table_name = '|| t.table_name ||';';
                            
                        END LOOP;
                        END LOOP;
                    END LOOP;
END;
$$
LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```

I get this error `SQL Error [42703]: ERROR: column "age" does not exist`. the table age does exist.
when I take out the where clause

```sql
    execute 'update referralunion.testinsert ti set records = (select count(*) from ' || s.table_schema || '.' || t.table_name || ') ;';
```

it works, I just cant figure out whats wrong?

Comment: Please post your *complete* function incl. header and declarations. Show your table definition (`CREATE TABLE` script), some sample data, and always your Postgres version.

Comment: One thing I see is `CREATE TABLE referralunion.table_study ...` then in the function `... FROM test.table_study`. So the function is not referring to the same table.

Answer (score 0):

Your procedure is structured entirely wrong. What it results in is an attempt to get every column name for every table name in every schema. I would guess results in your *column does not exist error*. Further is shows procedural thinking. SQL requires think in terms of sets. Below I use basically your query to demonstrate then a revised version which uses a single loop.

```
-- setup (dropping schema references)
create table table_study ( 
    table_schema text,
    table_name  text,
    column_name text,
    records     int,
    no_nulls    int,
    no_blanks   int,
    per_pop     int
);
    
insert into table_study(table_schema, table_name, column_name) 
     values ('s1','t1','age')
          , ('s2','t1','xyz'); 

-- procedure replacing EXECUTE with Raise Notice.     
create or replace procedure insert_data_population()
as $$
declare 
    s record;
    t record;
    c record;

    line int = 0;
begin

    for s in select distinct table_schema from table_study
    loop
        for t in select distinct table_name from table_study where table_schema = s.table_schema
        loop
            for c in select column_name from table_study where table_name = t.table_name
            loop        
               line = line+1;                 
               raise notice  '%: update  table_study set records = (select count(*) from  %.% where table_study.table_name =  %;'
                           , line, s.table_schema, t.table_name, c.column_name; 
               
            end loop;
        end loop;
    end loop;       
end;                 
$$ 
language plpgsql;
```

Run procedure

```
do $$ 
begin 
    call insert_data_population();
end;
$$;
```

RESULTS

1: update  table_study set records = (select count(*) from  s2.t1 where table_study.table_name =  age;  
  2: update  table_study set records = (select count(*) from  s2.t1 where table_study.table_name =  xyz;  
  3: update  table_study set records = (select count(*) from  s1.t1 where table_study.table_name =  age;  
  4: update  table_study set records = (select count(*) from  s1.t1 where table_study.table_name =  xyz;

Notice lines 2 and 3. Each references a column name that does not exist in the table. This results from the FOR structure with the same table name in different schema.

Revision for **Single Select** statement with Single For loop.

```
create or replace 
procedure insert_data_population()
 language plpgsql 
as $$
declare 
    s record;
    line int = 0;
begin

    for s in select distinct table_schema, table_name, column_name from table_study
    loop
        line = line+1;                 
        raise notice  '%: update  table_study set records = (select count(*) from  %.% where table_study.table_name =  %;'
                   ,  line, s.table_schema, s.table_name, s.column_name; 
    end loop;       
end;                 
$$;

do $$ 
begin 
    call insert_data_population();
end;
$$;
```

RESULTS  
1: update  table_study set records = (select count(*) from  s2.t1 where table_study.table_name =  xyz;  
2: update  table_study set records = (select count(*) from  s1.t1 where table_study.table_name =  age;

Note: In Postgres DECLARE begins a block. It is not necessary to declared each variable. I would actually consider it bad practice. In theory it could require an end for each declare as each could be considered a nested block. Fortunately Postgres does not require this.

Comment: Thank you so much ! truly appreciate your time for such an in depth answer